# Java7 StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_CREATE file write completition

Tags: java, events, filesystems, nio

I am using the new io api for the file system provided by the java 7 openjdk implementation. My application watches for events every couple of seconds and examines the collected events list for the type StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_CREATE. My question is, does ENTRY_CREATE correspond to the initial creation of the file in the file system or the completion of the write procedure ?

For example, if there is an application that writes a big image to the disk that takes ten seconds to complete, when will the ENTRY_CREATE event get fired, at second 0 or second 10?

Answer (score 1):

ENTRY_CREATE corresponds to the creation of a directory entry, be it a file or nested directory. Watch service won't tell you when writing to a file started or completed.